# Get data created x minutes ago in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a query, with PHP date or Carbon to get data created x minutes ago?

In my example, I need all data created 3 minutes ago. If the time is 10:00 and data was created, then at when query is made 10:03, I should get all data created at 10:00. If query made 10:04, no data show be returned.

> Edit per answer: To return all data created between 3 minutes ago and now.

```
use App/Foo
use Carbon\Carbon;

[...]

$three_minutes_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(3)->toDateTimeString();
$foo = Foo::where('created_at', '<', $three_minutes_ago)->get(); // Is this correct?
```

`$foo` is always empty no matter data is in `Foo`. I've used `tinker` to create/save data,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just tested and this is a working solution:

```
Foo::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subMinutes(3), now()])->get()
```

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that works? My array is still empty. What your code does, please?

Comment: Ok I get what works. Could you update your answer to match what works for me? `Foo::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subMinutes(3), now()])->get();`

Comment: @Sylar I thought you want to get only data that were created 3 minutes ago. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh! I get it, you thought I wanted a specific data. Sorry. I meant to say all data created `within` .... Sorry. But your first code will come in handy. Thanks again!

Comment: for me `Carbon::now()` worked ! `now()` didn't fit with my timezone ...